# Handlebars template refer to an object with dot operator

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have an object like this :

[image]

Now I wish to loop inside daily.data[] using Handlebars template.
I tried :

```
{{#daily.data}}
.
.
{{/daily.data}}
```

But I get console error :

```
 handlebars-v4.0.5.js:519 Uncaught Error: daily.data doesn't match daily - 1:3
```

Please guide on the same. Thanks

Comment: that object that you logged is not called daily. daily is the object inside that object. This is the reason for the error

Comment: Thanks Akshay...I am not logged in from any account. Could you please explain your point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use it like this. With a specific index.

```
{{daily.data.0}}
```

or iterate over the object like this:

```
{{#each daily.data}}
      {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

If you want to access a specific value, do it like this: `{{this.YOUR_VALUE}}`

Comment: thanks a lot... was forgetting #each. This worked great

Answer (score 1):

When you use each in handlebars it will give current object on each pass, so you can directly use that property.

```
{{#each data}}
<span class="address-add1">{{prop1}} </span>
<span class="address-add1">{{prop2}} </span>
{{/each}}
```